# Netlify Custom Email

Tags: reactjs, email, imap, netlify

### Problem:

I want to switch from hostgator to netlify, but the biggest issue is **I am unable to figure out or find documentation so far on how to either transfer existing emails or create new ones for a custom domain.**

### Example:

If I get a new domain from Netlify called Example.com, how do I **create an email such as Name@Example.com that can be accessed via IMAP etc?**

**I appreciate any help or documentation** that can be offered to achieve this. If possible, I would like it to be similar to cpanel in the sense that I can create custom emails on the fly with my own domain for receiving.

As another example: *for hostgator and using cpanel* I can simply click emails, add new and manage all of the custom emails in one place.

So if I have a custom domain Example.com I can create feedback@Example.com, subscribe@example.com, employee_name@example.com etc etc.

#### Is there any way to do this using Netlify?? I've been searching but have not found anything to answer this.

Comment: I'll vote to close as "is not about programming" but the a more exact reason would be ["is about customer service"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot accomplish your goal purely via Netlify, as Netlify is not an email host; you'll need a different service to handle that.  You can still host your sites and even DNS with Netlify while handling email with other services.

This Support Guide on their forums has more information:  https://answers.netlify.com/t/support-guide-how-can-i-receive-emails-on-my-domain/178